# Is there a way to add a function in an SP app that informs you when someone adds a new item in a list?

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I have an app that is connected to a list and I want to put a function in it that informs me when someone adds a new item in the list, it could be an alert message or something like that.
Any ides?

Answer (score 1):

A OOTB alert for the list will do it. Select the user/users/groups that should recieve the notification, for what type of changes and on what type of actions that should trigger the alert.

You can choose to send alert based on :

- All changes
- New items are added
- Existing items are modified
- Items are deleted

[Create an alert or subscribe to an RSS feed](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-alert-or-subscribe-to-an-RSS-feed-e5a79e7b-a146-46da-a9ef-d65409ba8918)

Comment: Thx user 19952, but  I would like to get alert message or something like it in app when changes are ,made in the list.